# Product order form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create an order form with 3 level dynamic dropdown list, item list future, closable button list item future, contact form future.

The “steps” that want to work is:

```
step 1: choose products of 3 level dynamic dropdown lists
step 2: click the “Add product to list”
step 3: the user can delete the product line IF he / she makes a mistake in the product details
step 4: insert contact information to contact form
step 5: click the submit button to send the product order with contact information to my email.
```

The code i found throw sites, i make some changes:

```js
function populate(s1, s2){ 
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if(s1.value == "Vitamin C"){
    var optionArray = ["|", "100mg|100mg", "500mg|500mg", "1000mg|1000mg"];
  } else if(s1.value == "Good Fats"){
    var optionArray = ["|", "omega 3 500ng|omega 3 500ng", "omega 3 1000ng|omega 3 1000ng", "omega 3 2000ng|omega 3 2000ng"];
  } else if(s1.value == "Minerals"){
    var optionArray = ["|", "magnesium citrate|magnesium citrate", "magnesium sulfate|magnesium sulfate"];
  }

  for(var option in optionArray){
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption,value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }   
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("slct0").reset();
}

var numadded = 0;

function doReset() {}

function checkData() {}

function doAdd() {
  // Pick up data from the category and value input fields;
  // In my form these are named 'cat' and 'val'
  var catstr = document.getElementById("slct1").value;
  var valstr = document.getElementById("slct2").value;
  var quantstr = document.getElementById("slct3").value;

  // Create a regex that checks for decimal numbers with
  // optional fractions. The regex expression states that
  // 1. the whole string must match ^...$
  // 2. there must be one or more decimal digits.
  // 3. optional there is a decimal point character.
  // 4. there may be digits following the decimal point.
  // In Javascript, you create a RegExp object giving it
  // the pattern that it must check.
  // var numpattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$");
  // Check that the "value" field matches the regex
  // if(!numpattern.test(valstr)) {
  //   alert("Non numeric data in values field");
  //   return;
  // }
  // The other pattern says a string of letters, digits, and spaces
  var catpattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$");
  if (!catpattern.test(catstr)) {
    alert("FIRST CHOOSE CATEGORY");
    return;
  }

  var valpattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$");
  if (!valpattern.test(valstr)) {
    alert("YOU NED TO CHOOSE PRODUCT");
    return;
  }

  var quantpattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$");
  if (!quantpattern.test(quantstr)) {
    alert("CHOOSE QUANTITY");
    return;
  }
  // If data looks ok, pick up references to the text areas; in
  // my page these had id values catlist and numlist
  var cats = document.getElementById("catlist");
  var nums = document.getElementById("numlist");
  var quant = document.getElementById("quantitylist");
  // Append text, inserting a new line character between
  // data sets.
  if (numadded > 0) {
    cats.value = cats.value + "\n";
    nums.value = nums.value + "\n";
    quant.value = quant.value + "\n";
  }

  var catOption = new Option(catstr, valstr);
  var numOption = new Option(valstr, valstr);
  var quantOption = new Option(quantstr, quantstr);
  numadded++;
  cats.appendChild(catOption);
  nums.appendChild(numOption);
  quant.appendChild(quantOption);
}

/* Get all elements with class="close" */
var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;

/* Loop through the elements, and hide the parent, when clicked on */
for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
  closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
    
reset[type=button] {
    width: 30%;    
}

input[type=button] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px;
}

#list {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background: #bbb;
}

#list td, #list th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    
}

#list tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#list tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#list th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
 
p.a { 
    word-spacing: 10px;;
}    
    
/* Add a light grey background color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* Style the close button (span) */
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.close:hover {background: #bbb;}
    
    
.mystyle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}   
    
    
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
    
.slct0 {
    background: #bbb;       
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="slct0" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="(slct1, slct2, slct3); return false;">
<p class="a">CHOOSE CATEGORY</P>

     <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct3')">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Vitamin C">Vitamin C</option>
        <option value="Good Fats">Good Fats</option>
        <option value="Minerals">Minerals</option>
    </select>  
    </p>
    <p></p>
    CHOOSE PRODUCT
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>             
   </p>
    <p>
        
        <option value="">CHOOSE CATEGORY</option>
        <select id="slct3" name="slct3">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
            <option value="32">32</option>
            <option value="33">33</option>
            <option value="34">34</option>
            <option value="35">35</option>
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="37">37</option>
            <option value="38">38</option>
            <option value="39">39</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
            <option value="41">41</option>
            <option value="42">42</option>
            <option value="43">43</option>
            <option value="44">44</option>
            <option value="45">45</option>
            <option value="46">46</option>
            <option value="47">47</option>
            <option value="48">48</option>
            <option value="49">49</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="51">51</option>
            <option value="52">52</option>
            <option value="53">53</option>
            <option value="54">54</option>
            <option value="55">55</option>
            <option value="56">56</option>
            <option value="57">57</option>
            <option value="58">58</option>
            <option value="59">59</option>
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="61">61</option>
            <option value="62">62</option>
            <option value="63">63</option>
            <option value="64">64</option>
            <option value="65">65</option>
            <option value="66">66</option>
            <option value="67">67</option>
            <option value="68">68</option>
            <option value="69">69</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
            <option value="71">71</option>
            <option value="72">72</option>
            <option value="73">73</option>
            <option value="74">74</option>
            <option value="75">75</option>
            <option value="76">76</option>
            <option value="77">77</option>
            <option value="78">78</option>
            <option value="79">79</option>
            <option value="80">80</option>
            <option value="81">81</option>
            <option value="82">82</option>
            <option value="83">83</option>
            <option value="84">84</option>
            <option value="85">85</option>
            <option value="86">86</option>
            <option value="87">87</option>
            <option value="88">88</option>
            <option value="89">89</option>
            <option value="90">90</option>
            <option value="91">91</option>
            <option value="92">92</option>
            <option value="93">93</option>
            <option value="94">94</option>
            <option value="95">95</option>
            <option value="96">96</option>
            <option value="97">97</option>
            <option value="98">98</option>
            <option value="99">99</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" onmousedown="doAdd()" onmouseup="myFunction()" value="Add product to list">
    
    
</form>
</div>
    
    
    
<div>           
                    <h1>My List</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table id="list" width="100%" align="center" border="0px">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5">CATEGORY</th>
                    <th colspan="35">PRODUCT</th>
                    <th colspan="35">QUANTITY</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" id="catlist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
                    
                    <td colspan="35" id="numlist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
                    
                    <td colspan="5" id="quantitylist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
                
               
                </table>
        </form>


<h3>Contact Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can not find the solution to make the list to be with rows item list and etch row have closable button list item future for step3! And last find a solution to make the submit button of contact list to sent the product list with contact information to my email.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: could you please make sure that we can run the code snippet here on stackoverflow? Right now it generates a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Lefteris, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the following URL so you can know how to ask a good question :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
We are here ready to help

Comment: Please take a minute and format your js code with placing the brackets after corect number of spaces.

Comment: Do you know how to send the contact form to your email?

Answer (score 0):

**TABLE Solution**

You create a new column in your table. Please see below. After that you should be able to create a function which delete the actual line showing.

Possible you should use the `document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);`-DOM property. [W3 reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp)

*Please be strict with ending/begin your tags.*

```
<h1>My List</h1>
<br>
<br>
<table id="list" width="100%" align="center" border="0px">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="5">CATEGORY</th>
  <th colspan="35">PRODUCT</th>
  <th colspan="35">QUANTITY</th>
  <th colspan="35">Action</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" id="catlist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
  <td colspan="35" id="numlist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
  <td colspan="5" id="quantitylist" style="width: 250px;" /></td>
  <td colspan="5" id="deletelist" style="width: 250px;" /><a href="#" onClick="PutYourActionHere">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

**FORM Solution**

You already direct to this page `action_page.php`.What happens at this page?

`<form id="slct0" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="(slct1, slct2, slct3); return false;">`

I have this from a former project. This might be help for you. The refence in `$_POST[''];` should be linked to an existing input in your form with the "id"-attribute to be able to retrieved. They should be named the exact same. $email is just to convert it into a variable that can be used.
First in `$formcontent` we are creating the message that you will receive. `\n` means "line break". The rest should be self explainable.

```
<?php
//Input from fomr
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
$land = $_POST['land'];

//Create email from here and send it to receiver
$formcontent=" From: $email \n Firma: $company \n Navn: $name \n Adresse: $adress , $areacode \n Land: $land \n Telefon: $phone \n Ringes op: $call \n Type: $type \n Besked: \n $message \n Vedhæftede filer: \n $path_of_uploaded_file";
$recipient = "email to receive form";
$subject = "Message from Sender";
$mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: http://www.myhomepage.com/thank_you.shtml');
?>
```